# How should I do to read socket which will be blocked in python with asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, asyncsocket

In the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.sock_recv), with the event loop, the sock must be non-blocking. But if it will be blocked, what should I do to read this socket in the asyncio event loop.

I try to use [loop.add_reader](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=add_reader#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.add_reader), but the callback function can not be a coroutine.

I come up with a solution to handle this situation, but I am not sure that it is the best.

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import events

loop = events.get_event_loop()

loop.add_reader(blocking_sock, read_data, sock)

def read_data(sock):
   """this callback function will only be a function"""
   data = sock.recv(1024)
   asyncio.ensure_future(handle_data_coroutine(data))

async def handle_data_coroutine(data)
    await do_something()
```

Comment: What about using [`socket.setblocking(False)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking)?

Comment: Do you have to use an existing socket? Ideally you'd call [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) which creates the socket and wraps it in streams.

Comment: I need to use the socket which is accessed from attach_socket docker container.